# Mpdf different header for first page

Tags: php, mpdf

I am working on quotation software where I am using mpdf for quotation generation using HTML format. Header are set by code below.

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
$mpdf=>SetHTMLFooter($footer);
```

Which applies uniformly to all pages. But I need different header to first page. How should I achieve it?

Answer (score 22):

As you wrote, `SetHTMLHeader` and `SetHTMLFooter` apply to the entire document. If you want different headers / footers for the first page you will have to remove both

```
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
```

And do it like so:

1. In your PDF's HTML code, place right after the `<body>` tag the different header definitions like so:

> ```
> <htmlpageheader name="firstpage" style="display:none">
>     <div style="text-align:center">First Page</div>
> </htmlpageheader>
>
> <htmlpageheader name="otherpages" style="display:none">
>     <div style="text-align:center">{PAGENO}</div>
> </htmlpageheader>
> ```

2. Set your headers like this (still in you first page's code)

> ```
> <sethtmlpageheader name="firstpage" value="on" show-this-page="1" />
> <sethtmlpageheader name="otherpages" value="on" />
> ```

This turns on both headers but on the first page shows the "firstpage" header.

3. Same goes for footers.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**

There are actually a few ways to go about it. They are all documented [here](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/headers-footers.html). I chose to write here the one I think is the most straight forward and will easily work, but I recommend you read the docs and choose the one that best suits your needs.

Comment: This solution causes layout problems if the headers are not of the same height.

Answer (score 12):

As Yotam said, there's other ways to acomplish this. If you are using CSS to style your page, as usual, you may find the [@page](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=307) selector useful. It should be something like this:

```
@page {
    header: html_otherpages;
}

@page :first {
    header: html_firstpage;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: Can you please add a example for that

Comment: Works for me. You can find example from here
https://gravitypdf.com/documentation/v3/headers-and-footers-pdf-template-example/

Answer (score 11):

place right after the `<body>`

```
<htmlpageheader name="firstpageheader" style="display:none">
    <div style="text-align:center"> first page header</div>
</htmlpageheader>

<htmlpagefooter name="firstpagefooter" style="display:none">
    <div style="text-align:center">first page footer</div>
</htmlpagefooter>

<htmlpageheader name="otherpageheader" style="display:none">
    <div style="text-align:center"> all page Header</div>
</htmlpageheader>

<htmlpagefooter name="otherpagesfooter" style="display:none">
    <div style="text-align:center">all page footer </div>
</htmlpagefooter>
```

In CSS use following :

```
@page {  
    header: html_otherpageheader;
    footer: html_otherpagesfooter;
}

@page :first {    
    header: html_firstpageheader;
    footer: html_firstpagefooter;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can cheat the system

```
//set your header firstpage
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($headerFirstpage); 
//set your footer firstpage
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footerFirstpage);   
//write a space 
$mpdf->WriteHTML(' ');
//set your header
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($header); 
//set your footer
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer); 
//set your content
$mpdf->WriteHTML($content);
```