# mPDF hide header from first and last page

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm using the following code to add a header and footer on every page of my PDF:

```
global $pdf_footer;
global $pdf_header;

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<img src="header.jpg"/>');
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('<img src="footer.jpg"/>');
```

This works great but i would like t remove the header and footer from the 1st and last page. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: If you're using HTML check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670208/mpdf-different-header-for-first-page Also, the docs have a nice guide on using different types of headers and footers and creating different ones for different first/last pages.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to SO. How do i mark your answer as perfect and give you credit?

Comment: And thank you for your help!

Comment: You can only upvote the comments, they can't be selected as answers. Only the full fledged answers can be accepted. Just upvote the answers on the question page that I've linked and that you've found helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

**Approach 1: Using HTML & PHP (Recommended for simplicity)**

You can conditionally set the header content in PHP based on the page number. mPDF provides the {PAGENO} and {nbpg} placeholders, which can be used to determine the current page number and the total number of pages, respectively. However, you'll need to customize your approach slightly, as these placeholders are meant for use within the document body or header/footer content directly and don't directly support conditional logic for displaying content.

That said, you can implement logic in your PHP code that adds headers only if certain conditions are met (e.g., not on the first or last page). Here's a conceptual example:

```
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    
    // Assume $html contains your main content
    
    // First page
    $mpdf->AddPage();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    
    // Add header from the second page to the second-to-last page
    $mpdf->SetHeader('Your Header Content Here');
    for ($i = 2; $i < $totalPages; $i++) {
        $mpdf->AddPage();
        // Update $html or add different content per page as needed
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    }
    
    // Last page - without header
    $mpdf->SetHeader('');
    $mpdf->AddPage();
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    
    $mpdf->Output(); ?>
```

**Approach 2: Custom HTML Headers with Conditional Logic**

Another way is to embed PHP (if generating your HTML content with PHP) or JavaScript (less recommended as it relies on client-side execution which is not applicable for mPDF) within your HTML to conditionally render headers. Since mPDF executes PHP server-side when generating the PDF, you can't directly use {PAGENO} or {nb} in PHP conditionals without pre-processing or estimating page numbers, which can be complex and error-prone.

For most use cases, the first approach is more straightforward and effective. It involves controlling the header content through PHP logic before each page is added to the document.

Remember, mPDF processes HTML and PHP that's passed to it before generating the PDF, so any dynamic logic related to page numbers needs to be handled with PHP on the server side before passing the final content to mPDF for PDF generation.

[How to Conditionally Hide Headers on the First and Last Page with mPDF](https://www.tutorialwala.com/how-to-conditionally-hide-headers-on-the-first-and-last-page-with-mpdf/)